# How to manually trigger CLLocationManager update?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, core-location

I am monitoring the users location with these configurations:

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

I have a switch that allows the user to either enter an address manually or allow for GPS tracking. When toggling from manual to GPS location, I'd like to kick the `CLLocationManager` to update the users location and call the `didUpdateLocations` event. Otherwise, it just waits and waits to update when it feels like it. Is manually triggering an update one time possible?

Answer (score 3):

from the docs:

*startUpdatingLocation*

*Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling stopUpdatingLocation in between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this method.*

so you could stop and immediately restart the location updates to trigger it manually!

Answer (score 0):

> Is manually triggering an update one time possible

Yes, but not with `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. You will need to call `startUpdatingLocation`. Note that even then it may take several calls to your delegate, and several seconds, before you get your single usable update.

What I do ([example code here](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift)) is to watch both the `horizontalAccuracy` and the `timestamp`, and stop when I *either* get a sufficiently accurate location *or* too much time elapses.

Answer (score 0):

Start it when you want to start scanning for updates, but not when you want an immediate location.

If you want an immediate location, request it with `manager.location`. If the response is `nil` then no location is currently available and you need to wait. If a location is returned you can check the `timestamp` to determine if you can use it.